# Angular 2+, rtlcss integration

Tags: css, angular, webpack, postcss, bidi

I have a task to add rtl support to the site by using some kind of a library to modify css which will swap left to right and vice versa and append [dir=rlt] [dir=ltr] to all selectors accordingly.

What I have done so far:

- called ng eject
- added rtlcss processor as postcss plugin, but it does not fit my requirements. I need it to append [dir=*] to selectors.
- tried other plugins but they did not work.

Possible solutions:

- make two css files and dynamically load them. (but then you need to add ViewEncapsulation.None to all components) **BAD, not so much work, but can break layout**
- make two css files and run as two different applications. One for rtl, one for ltr. **BAD, no resources for that**
- make rtl by hand. **BAD, too much work**

  - forget about rtl processors and make sass mixins. **BAD, too much work**
- make one css file with correct prefixes generated, [dir=ltr] and [dir=rtl] which will result in a doubly sized css but it will eventually work. **GOOD but no idea how to do it**

  - create custom library to do this, or fork existing to modify
  - find working processor

Currently, I am trying to find working processor with no luck.

Are there any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: did you solve the problem eventually?